# When did the Jews stop visiting the Kaaba?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, islamic-events, kaabah, jews

I was reading in chapter 2 of [Martin Lings' biography of Muhammad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594771537) that the Jews stopped visiting the Kaaba after pilgrims started bringing idols there. There's a citation of [Ibn Ishaq 15](https://archive.org/stream/TheLifeOfMohammedGuillaume/The_Life_Of_Mohammed_Guillaume#page/n27/mode/1up), but I don't see how it relates.

Are there traditions or scholarship that specify when the Jews stopped visiting the Kaaba, either with an approximate date or with other events that were happening around the same time?

Comment: Did you look at the passage in Ibn Ishaq (top of the right-hand page)? It says why they stopped visiting the Ka'ba, though not when.

Comment: @aasheq Yes, and it also seems to indicate that at the time of that conversation, they hadn't been going for quite some time.